# Login doesn't work even if data is present in SQLite database

Tags: java, database, sqlite, javafx, authentication

I have a database and it has a table `user` which consists of many attributes like name ,email,etc. Also it has `username` and `password` in VARCHAR datatype. I wrote two classes `LoginModel` and `Controller`. controller has method `loginit` through which it checks if `login` method from `LoginModel` returns true or not. I am not able to find out why `LoginModel` always returns false. Please help.

Here are my methods :

**from class LoginModel**

```
public boolean login(String userid, String userpass) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
    try{
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1,userid);
        preparedStatement.setString(2,userpass);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        if(resultSet.next()){
            return true;
        }
        else {
           // System.out.println(resultSet.next());
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        return false;
    }
    finally {
        preparedStatement.close();
        resultSet.close();
        return false;
    }
}
```

**from class Controller**

```
public void loginit() throws SQLException {
    String userid = uid.getText();
    String userpass = upass.getText();
    try {
        if (loginmodel.login(userid, userpass)) {
            lblstatus.setText("YES");
        }
        else
            lblstatus.setText("Invalid");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        lblstatus.setText("No");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

It is a JavaFX application. `userid` and `userpass` are ids of text-field and password-field respectively. `lblstatus` is label which always shows `Invalid`, can't figure out why!

Here is snapshot of my database

[image]

Comment: I think you get en exception in your SQL code. printout the stacktrace and you will see what is happend

Comment: NO, in case of exception it prints out `NO` which is why I put `Invalid` in else loop. Else it will print stacktrace

Comment: NO!!. You catch the exception` catch (Exception e){
        return false;
    }` and return `false`

Comment: Ohh ohk in loginmodel. let me check. btw i renamed password to passkey coloumn still same .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `return false` from the `finally` block. It will executed in case of execption and in case you get no exception.

```
finally {
        preparedStatement.close();
        resultSet.close();
        return false;
    }
```

Change your code to:

```
public boolean login(String userid, String userpass) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
    try{
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1,userid);
        preparedStatement.setString(2,userpass);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        if(resultSet.next()){
            return true;
        }
        else {
           // System.out.println(resultSet.next());
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        return false;
    }
    finally {
        preparedStatement.close();
        resultSet.close();
    }
       return false;

}
```

Comment: thank you ! it worked, silly mistake of mine . I don't understand why my Q is marked as duplicate!